# Gitzilla - hook declined to update refs/heads/master and missing/incomplete bugzilla conf (no bugzilla_url)

Tags: git, bugzilla, gitzilla

I have configured gitzilla in my machine having GIT repository with all required dependencies.

In the `~/.gitzillarc` file I have provided the necessary configurations with valid bugzilla url and credentials. But, whenever I try to push a change to the master, the following error message is displayed:

`Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 210 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
** remote: missing/incomplete bugzilla conf (no bugzilla_url)
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master **
To xxx@xxx:/home/yyy.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)`

Please guide to find a necessary solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: There was no solution available online. I just tried all possible ways and re-worked on this from scratch! With correct version of pybugz, other dependencies and correct configuration, I made this work. Are you facing any issue related to this?

Comment: I think 'other dependencies' may be my problem.  With pybugz installed at v0.8.0 (and also 0.9.2), I got past this original problem, however now I get a login error.  My conf looks good to me, the only noticeable difference from the examples being http instead of https in the bugzilla url.  The log file says oBZ.auth() is throwing the error, originating in bugz/bugzilla.py `raise(RuntimeError("Failed to login")`.  I might see if pybugz has logging I can enable as well.  So I suspect an underlying install issue with the old pybugz version.

Comment: Pybugz sure has logging. Add the below mentioned two lines:          `logfile:<Path_to_your_log_file>/bugz.log
  loglevel: debug`

Comment: Have you added **xmlrpc.cgi** in your bugzilla URL?

Comment: I can't get pybugz to use my config files so I can't set the log file location.

Comment: Could you provide the details of configuration file that you have currently. So that I can check whether you have done any mistake or not

Comment: Thanks Orochimaru, I made a new question for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349600/pybugz-cannot-login-to-bugzilla-from-pybugz