# Cannot login to Bugzilla from PyBugz

Tags: bugzilla, pybugz

I am having trouble authenticating my bugzilla user from pybugz.

PyBugz v0.9.3
Bugzilla v4.4.6

I'm using this older version of pybugz because I believe I need it for gitzilla.

Anonymous login to bugzilla has been allowed by setting the option requirelogin = off.

I can successfully retrieve a bug anonymously with this command
`bugz -b http://bugs.domain.org.au --skip-auth get 1`

but when I attempt to authenticate with this
`bugz -b http://bugs.domain.org.au -u me@bugs.domain.org.au -p mypassword get 1`

I receive this message

```
* Using http://bugs.domain.org.au
* Getting bug 1 ..  
! Error: Failed to login
```

The username and password in the console command above are the same that I use to login to bugzilla from a web browser.

The contents of ~/.bugzrc are:

```
[bugs]  
base: http://bugs.domain.org.au/xmlrpc.cgi  
user: me@domain.org.au  
password: mypassword  
httpuser: me  
httppassword: mypassword  
logfile: /var/log/pybugz.log  
loglevel: debug  
forget: True  
columns: 80  
encoding: utf-8  
quiet: False
```

Same thing happens using the config file:
`bugz --connection bugs --skip-auth get 1` works
`bugz --connection bugs get 1` does not work
Nothing is written to the log file.  The log file permissions are myuser:root 666.

Comment: Bugzilla updated its login tokens and pybugz supports the new tokens in HEAD.  Here's the bug https://github.com/williamh/pybugz/issues/78

Comment: It seems what I really need is a python3 version of gitzilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bugzilla changed their authentication mechanism in v4.4.3.
Pybugz added support for the new authentication but also dropped support for python 2.

Since Gitzilla requires pybugs I had to port gitzilla to python 3 and then add the token support.

You can clone it here: https://github.com/gtait/gitzilla
Tested and working with Bugzilla 4.4.6 and 4.2.11 using pybugz 0.11.1 on python3.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are lot of issues when we try to integrate Pybugz 0.9.3 and Bugzilla 4.4 and above. [This link](https://github.com/williamh/pybugz/issues/63) says that the issue has been fixed with the latest version of Pybugz.

So, try installing the latest version of Pybugz, possibly 0.11.1 with Python version 3.x and then integrate it with your version of Bugzilla.

If it doesn't work then you need to downgrade your version of Bugzilla and it is quite easy to integrate it with Pybugz 0.9.3.

Comment: Thanks Orochimaru.  The main problem arose from the latest changes to Bugzilla.